# Can't make my observable notification system work with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm failing to use the rxjs Observable in Angular2 to build my notification system.

I have build my notification service like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  private notifications: BehaviorSubject<{}> = new BehaviorSubject<{}>({});

  constructor() {
  }

  notify(message: string, type: string) {
    // Seems to do nothing ?
    this.notifications.next(
      { 'type': type, 'message': message }
    );
  }

  notifyError(message: string) {
    this.notify(message, 'error');
  }

  notifyInfo(message: string) {
    this.notify(message, 'info');
  }

  notifyWarning(message: string) {
    this.notify(message, 'warning');
  }

  notifyPrimary(message: string) {
    this.notify(message, 'primary');
  }

  notifySuccess(message: string) {
    this.notify(message, 'success');
  }

  onNotification(): Observable<{}> {
    return this.notifications.asObservable();
  }
}
```

It seems that this.notifications.next does nothing or that the component that subscribe to this service is not able to receive notification.

In this component i have this code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.onNotification().subscribe(
      notification => { data => console.log("notification", data.message) },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

I can log notification triggered by other component in the notify* methods of my NotificationService.

This is the plunker for my case : http://plnkr.co/edit/A8G22puWedxF5fAWyvYI

Comment: Can't find any issue. Code works fine for me. Can you reproduce it in a plunkr?

Comment: Try to replace `notification => { data => console.log("notification", data.message) },` with `(data: any) => console.log("notification", data.message),` Seems you have a double wrapper

Comment: yurzui this change nothing.
I added a plunker example

Comment: Check it http://plnkr.co/edit/ITnd5R5H4NRKqM9yy4Ir?p=preview

Comment: ohh nice, i have tested the wrong code notification => (data: any) => console.log("notification", data.message).
Sorry my bad. This work fine. thx you so much. But can you explain the difference between both?